# maximum and minimum value of $\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+xy+4y^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

> If $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ and $x^2+y^2>0.$ Then maximum and minimum value of $\displaystyle \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+xy+4y^2}$

Plan

Let $$K=\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+xy+4y^2}$$

$$Kx^2+Kxy+4Ky^2=x^2+y^2\Rightarrow (4K-1)y^2+Kxy+(K-1)x^2=0$$

put $y/x=t$ and equation is $(4K-1)t^2+Kt+(K-1)=0$

How do i solve it Help me plesse

Comment: And, just graphing it, only when $K$ is equal to $1$, does anything show up. When $K$ is equal to $1$, there are no minima or maxima.

Comment: It is interesting that the function is like the reciprocal of the Rayleigh coefficient of a certain matrix, that would help. Indeed, the minimum and maximum of this function will be related with the eigenvalues of the mateix. Give me some time, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Quote Davis Try graphing $K$ as a function of $t$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$K=\frac{1+t^2}{1+t+4t^2}$  To find min and max, set $K'(t)=0$ or $t^2-6t-1=0$ and solve for $t$. Answer $t=3\pm \sqrt{10}$ leading to max and min $K=\frac{20\pm 6\sqrt{10}}{80\pm 25\sqrt{10}}$. or $1.088303688022443$ and $0.245029645310883$

Corrected (stupid error in solving quadratic).

Comment: How did you know to do this? Just insight or a traditional technique?

Comment: @Chase Ryan Taylor standard calculus

Comment: I meant the substitution

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Note the correction.

Comment: What I mean is: For a general $f(x,y)$ to maximize, what is the formula for $K(t)$?

Comment: In this case dividing numerator and denominator by $x^2$ allowed a definition of $t=\frac{y}{x}$.  In general there may not be such a single variable to define $K$ as $K(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $v = (x,y)$,
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & 4 \end{bmatrix}
$$
and define the Rayleigh cuocient.
$$
R_A(v) = \frac{v^T A v}{v^Tv}.
$$
Then, it is clear that
$$
\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+xy+4y^2} = \frac{1}{R_A(v)}.
$$
It is well-known (Linear Algebra result) that $\operatorname{min}_{v \neq 0} R_A(v) = \lambda_{\operatorname{min}}$ and $\operatorname{max}_{v \neq 0} R_A(v) = \lambda_{\operatorname{max}}$, where $\lambda_{\operatorname{min}}$ and $\lambda_{\operatorname{max}}$ are the smallest and largest eigenvalues of $A$, respectively.

In this case $\lambda_{\operatorname{min}} = \frac{1}{2} \left(5-\sqrt{10}\right)$ and $\lambda_{\operatorname{max}} = \frac{1}{2} \left(5+\sqrt{10}\right)$. Therefore,
$$
\min_{x,y\neq 0} \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+xy+4y^2} = \frac{1}{\max_{v\neq 0} R_A(v)} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2} \left(5+\sqrt{10}\right)} = \frac{2}{15}(5+\sqrt{10})
$$
and
$$
\max_{x,y\neq 0} \frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+xy+4y^2} = \frac{1}{\min_{v\neq 0} R_A(v)} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{2} \left(5-\sqrt{10}\right)} = \frac{2}{15}(5-\sqrt{10}).
$$

Comment: +1: Nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

From the restriction $x^2+y^2>0$, we get that $x,y$ are not both zero.

If $x=0$, then $K={\large{\frac{1}{4}}}$.

Suppose $x\ne 0$.

Letting $t={\large{\frac{y}{x}}}$, and following your approach, we get
$$(4K-1)t^2+Kt+(K-1)=0$$
which has a real solution for $t$ if and only $K={\large{\frac{1}{4}}}$ or the discriminant
$$K^2-4(4K-1)(K-1)$$
is nonnegative.

Equivalently, either $K={\large{\frac{1}{4}}}$ or
$$-15K^2+20K-4\ge 0$$
With the restriction $K\ne{\large{\frac{1}{4}}}$, the quadratic inequality solves as
$$\frac{10-2\sqrt{10}}{15}\le K\le \frac{10+2\sqrt{10}}{15},\;\;K\ne{\large{\frac{1}{4}}}$$
Noting that 
$$\frac{10-2\sqrt{10}}{15}<\frac{1}{4}<\frac{10+2\sqrt{10}}{15}$$
it follows that

- The minimum value of $K$ is ${\large{\frac{10-2\sqrt{10}}{15}}}\approx .2450296455$.$\\[8pt]$

  The maximum value of $K$ is ${\large{\frac{10+2\sqrt{10}}{15}}}\approx 1.088303688$.